How did C. S. Peirce graphically represent a syllogism?
How did C. S. Peirce graphically represent a syllogism? Analogously to how Venn did?
For example, his Existential Graphs can prove Leibniz's Præclarum Theorema (Splendid Theorem) (source).

C. S. Peirce's Existential Graphs for Barbara (AAA), Celarent (EAE), Darii (AII), and Ferio (EIO) syllogisms:

courtesy: Dr. Frithjof Dau

Very interesting... do you have the source (Peirce's CP volume), or is it a modern reconstruction?

@MauroALLEGRANZA I think it's Dr. Dau's construction.

As is well-known, most of Peirce's studies were either scattered or unpublished (they are reprinted into the 8 vols of Collected Papers).
Peirce deals with syllogism in the fundamental 1885 On the Algebra of Logic, but there are no diagrams in it.
For the symbolic representation of traditional propositions, we can see Charles Sanders Peirce, The Logic of Relatives, The Monist (1897), page 174, Fig.7, for the diagram representing: "Anything whatever, if it be a man, is mortal."
See also Peirce's 1898 Cambridge Conferences, reprinted into Charles Sanders Peirce, Reasoning and the Logic of Things (1992, Harvard University Press), Lecture III, page 151, for the example regarding the conditional proposition [It is a species of disjunctive proposition]: "“If you obey mamma you are a good girl.”
See also Hilary Putnam's comment to graphs, page 69.
For the theory of Existential Graphs, see e.g. Sun-Joo Shin, The Iconic Logic of Peirce's Graphs (The MIT Press, 2002). Peirce's theory of Existential Graphs consists of three parts, which he calls Alpha, Beta, and Gamma Graphs, corresponding to propositional, relational and modal logic, respectively.
See also Don Roberts, The Existential Graphs of Charles S. Peirce (Mouton, 1973), page 61, for the example regarding Barbara syllogism extracted from some Peirce's manuscripts.
Some Peirce's manuscripts on boolean logic an Existential Graphs are reprinted into Vol.III of Peirce's New Elements of Mathematics; see page 162 (1911) and page 405 (Lowell Lectures, 1903).
The part starting at page 162 regarding existential graphs is available on-line.

Also interesting, the Stanhope Demonstrator, and see Robert Harley, The Stanhope Demonstrator (Mind, 1879) as well as Allan Marquand A New Logical Machine (Proc.Am.Academy of Arts and Sciences, 1885).

On the topic of logical diagrams in general, still useful: Martin Gardner, Logic Machines and Diagrams (McGraw-Hill, 1958) (cf. ch. 2: Logic Diagrams)
